# XML Namespace building with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I wanted to have `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'` appear in feed and entry tag.
But don't know why my entry tag is missing  `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'`

Here the result I wanted to achieve

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'> 
  <entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app' xmlns:sc='http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009' xmlns:scp='http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009/products'>
```

Here is my code

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.feed('xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
           'xmlns:batch' => 'http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch') do
              xml.entry('xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
                        'xmlns:app' => 'http://www.w3.org/2007/app',
                        'xmlns:sc' => 'http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009',
                        'xmlns:scp' => 'http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009/products')
           end
end
```

Comment: That's weird, nothing wrong on my machine.

Comment: @halfelf he is missing the `xmlns` tag in the `entry`.

Answer (score 0):

In XML, the `xmlns` tag is inherited by child nodes. Because `entry` is a child of `feed`, and they have the same value for `xmlns`, Nokogiri may be optimizing out the entry on the child node.